# start activity1, switch to activity2 (when done) , resume activity1 where it ended

Tags: android

I've got a MainActivity that starts PuzzleActivity, in PuzzleActivity half way I want to go to SizeSelection activiy (which has another layout) and when clicked one of the buttons that's in the layout and the process is done in the activity I want to resume the puzzleactivity where it ended (where it went to SizeSelection.

SizeSelection:

```
public static short getGridSize(Context content) {
        if ( mIbtn3x3 == view) {
            short gridSize = 3;
            return gridSize;
        }else if (mIbtn4x4 == view ) {
            short gridSize = 4;
            return gridSize;
        }else if (mIbtn5x5 == view ) {
            short gridSize = 5;
            return gridSize ;
        }
            return gridSize;
        }
```

PuzzleActivity:

```
Intent i5 = new Intent(this, SizeSelection.class);  
            startActivity(i5);
            createGameBoard(SizeSelection.getGridSize(this));
            break;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`. This way your launching activity will not be destroyed, but just like "paused", and so it's `onPause()` method will be called.

Then to return back to your first activity from the second one, when needed use :

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

and if you need to send back some data use an intent and the overloaded `setResult()` method :

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.put...
setResult(RESULT_OK, data); //RESULT_OK should be replaced by a positive int if you want to use the onActivityResult() method and get the data in the first activity
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
startActivityForResult()
```

instead of startActivity. When you're finished in the SizeSelection activity call

```
finish()
```

Then set grid size in.

```
onActivityResult()
```

More detailed description is here
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities